# Big intersection of a unique set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

**PART I**

I'm in chapter 2 of Enderton's set theory book and most of the problems I've run into in the exercises are about the **big intersection**, that is, given a set A, $\bigcap A$. By the definition it should be somethng of the kind $\bigcap A = \{a: \forall x \in A: a \in A\}$*, right?

But I'm not sure how to apply this to sets such as $A = \{1, 2\}$ (that I think $\bigcap A$ = $\emptyset$??) or $A = \{1\}$ (maybe $\bigcap A$ = $\{1\}$ or $\emptyset$??). Is there a limit to what kind of set can be "big intersectioned"? Also, is there a way to quickly tell if an intersection will be different from $\emptyset$?

*Just to make clear that the notation with index didn't appear yet in the book and it looks confusing to me.

**PART II**

**Exercise 27** asks: "Give an example of sets A and B for which $A \cap B$ is nonempty and $\bigcap A \cap \bigcap B \neq \bigcap (A \cap B)$ ".

My first thought was to make A and B equal, like this: $A = B = \{1\}$ and then $A \cap B = \{1\}$ (?) and $\bigcap (A \cap B) = \{ 1 \}$ (?) and $\bigcap A \cap \bigcap B = \{ 1 \} \cap \{ 1 \} = \{ 1 \} $??? but then the sets doesn't fit the question since they would be equal.

So my next step was try to identifies what could changes from A to B, since they must be different. And by this way I could find something like $A =\{ 1, \{ 1 \} \}$ and $B = \{ \{ 1 \} \}$, so $A \cap B = \{ \{ 1 \} \}$, $\bigcap A = \emptyset$ and $\bigcap A \cap \bigcap B = \emptyset$. And finally $\bigcap (A \cap B) = \{ 1 \}$.

I think it's correct but I'm having trouble finding a "heuristic" to solve the exercises, if you have any tips for a beginner, I'd appreciate a lot!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you aware of the usual set theoretic codification of the natural numbers? You can take the "big" intersection of any set *except* the empty set.

Comment: The intersection of a set is made of the elements of the elements of the set.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of $\bigcap \scr A$ is
$$\bigcap \mathscr A = \{a \mid \forall A \in \mathscr A, a \in A\}$$
The important thing to note here is: $\scr A$ is a set *of sets*. For this to be non-empty, every element $A \in \scr A$ has to be a set itself. Otherwise the condition $a \in A$ is nonsensical.

Now, it is THE THING to do these days to define set theory is such a way that everything is a set. There are no non-set objects ("urelements") in the theory. But even so, there are objects that you do not want to think of as being sets, even if under the skin they really are. These include numbers such as $0, 1, 2, 3, \dots$. If you were to consider these as sets, the question arises which sets they would be. If you use the Von Neumann construction of the natural numbers, then equivalence classes to define the Integers, the Rationals, the Reals, and the Complex numbers in turn, you have specific definitions as sets for $0, 1, 2, 3,\dots$ in each - but *each collection of numbers represents them as different sets than the others*. So even then it isn't clear which sets they would be.

So you don't want to talk about $\bigcap \{0, 1\}$. It either makes no sense, or it is some indeterminant set that you cannot know without specifying exactly what sets $0, 1$ are. It isn't a sensible thing to do.

But it is sensible to talk about such things as $\bigcap \{L^p(\Bbb R) \mid 1 \le p < \infty\}$, where each object in the collection being intersected is a well-defined set.

Comment: Hmmm okay, that  was very helpful! Thank you, Paul

Comment: For Part II, note that $\bigcap A$ consists of the things that are in every set in $A$, and similarly for $\bigcap B$. Thus $\bigcap A \cap \bigcap B$ consists of the things that are in every set in $A$ and in every set in $B$. But $\bigcap (A\cap B)$ consists of the things that are in every set that is common to $A$ and $B$. It may include items not in sets that are in $A$ only or in $B$ only.